# Этимология слова "причиндалы"

Tags: этимология

В словаре Фасмера лишь указано другое написание "причиндалы", а так никакой информации. Заранее благодарствую.

Comment: Да нормальный вопрос, не понятно, конечно, чего Владиславу не хватает в этимологическом словаре, например Ушакова:

ПРИЧИНДА́ЛЫ, причиндалов, ед. нет (прост. фам. шутл.). Предметы, являющиеся принадлежностью кого-чего-нибудь. Пришел водопроводчик со всеми своими причиндалами.

Comment: В нормальном вопросе не обозначена проблема: почему не получилось найти слово словаре?

Comment: У Фасмера: 
"п р и ч и н д а л ы, мн. "принадлежности", курск. (Даль) , причандалы мн. , яросл. (Волоцкий) . Неясно. " 

Специалисту-этимологу происхождение неясно. Он так и пишет, мол, теряюсь, товарищи, в догадках. 

Я считаю, что, если это принадлежности, то есть, то, что при+над+корень лежит, то и в причиндалах можно вычленить при+корень чин+ещё один корень, дал+ флексия множественного числа "ы". Причиндалы -- то, что дано по чину, то, что при чине, то, что положено. 
Источник:Это я так лично думаю.  https://otvet.mail.ru/question/53548878

Comment: @Sharon Да Фасмер, такое ощущение не всегда понимал русский, но у него задача была другая.

Comment: А какая у него была задача?

Comment: @Sharon создать словарь происхождения слов русского языка из других языков - из немецкого и польского. Он же немец был.

Comment: И сколько же таких слов он насчитал?  Много, наверное.  Интересная личность.  И потом он Русский немец белокурый...   https://dzen.ru/a/YQ19dva2UxxS0iXC  https://proza.ru/2012/04/02/1975

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152350/discussion-between--and-sharon).